# In LLVM IR with OpenMP, how do I get all the omp loops and the Instructions?

Tags: clang, openmp, llvm, llvm-ir

I managed to use clang with "-fopenmp" to get the LLVM IR of an OpenMP program. I saw the content and there are so much "omp" loops inside. I need to get all Instructions only from inside those omp loops. How do I do that?

For example, I want to get only the omp ones from :

```
for.end28:                                        ; preds = %for.cond
  br label %omp.body.continue, !dbg !468

omp.body.continue:                                ; preds = %for.end28
  br label %omp.inner.for.inc, !dbg !423

omp.inner.for.inc:                                ; preds = %omp.body.continue
  %47 = load i32, i32* %.omp.iv, align 4, !dbg !419
  %add29 = add nsw i32 %47, 1, !dbg !414
  store i32 %add29, i32* %.omp.iv, align 4, !dbg !414
  br label %omp.inner.for.cond, !dbg !423, !llvm.loop !469
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Start by posting the code that you have trouble with.

Comment: What do you mean by "*get all Instructions only from inside those omp loops*" ? What would be the expected *output*?

Comment: The output is the list of the instructions inside the omp

Comment: Ok but what do you mean by "instructions": C ones, assembly ones, LLVM-IR ones? Note that there are many pass in LLVM being performed, the IR is generally different after each pass. Which one matters to you? Assuming this is the instructions in the provided LLVM-IR code, then I do not see what is the problem because you can just extract the `omp` sections. What if there are functions calls, SIMD annotations, critical sections, etc.? Please be *much more* specific (as said previously by VictorEijkhout)

Comment: What I mean is the instructions in LLVM-IR code. And what I want to know is how to extract only the omp sections.